# How can I display a second wallpaper by clicking second button?

Tags: java, android, button, background-image

I've recently started developing apps. I want to display the wallpaper that I choose for users.

The first button works perfectly, but I don't know what code I need to use for the second button.

The same code does not work.

Here's my code:

```
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity<bitmap2> extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button1, buttons2, buttons3, buttons4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        buttons2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttons2);
        buttons3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttons3);
        buttons4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttons4);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setWallpaper();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setWallpaper() {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.str1);
        WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good appetite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: Is this javascript?

Comment: It looks more like code for Android not JS

Comment: ok I editted my question , what now ?

Comment: `First button works perfectly but I dont know what code I need to use for second button,`, what did you want to do with the second button?

Comment: Second button for another wallpaper